# Replacing old plug-in 220V range with new hardwire 3-wire electric cooktop: remove outlet or add a plug?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, 240v

My apartment had an electric range which plugged into NEMA 10-30P/10-50P and was served by two 50A circuits. I will be installing electric/220V induction cooktop using the same circuits.
[image: plug]
[image: breakers]

There are three wires in the plug (red, black and white).
[image: inside plug]

There are three wires in the new cooktop (red, black and green).
[image: plug]

Instructions say to connect the green wire from the cooktop to the white wire from the wall.   So far so good, except the outlet will need to be removed and some sort of extension box will need to be put in its place to allow the connection in the back of the cabinet.

Is it possible instead to put a plug at the end of the cooktop 3-wire cable?  If yes, then is there an advantage to doing that rather than hardwiring it?

Electrical requirements for new cooktop: 
    3-wire or 4-wire single phase 208 or 240 volt AC, 60-Hz, on dedicated double pole circuit breaker of *at least* 40 amps.

For the old range: 
    "You must use a single-phase, 120/208 VAC or 120/240 VAC, 60 hertz electrical system. ... connected to an individual, properly grounded, 40 amp (minimum) branch circuit"

I'm in NYC if that matters.

Here is my attempt at picture of the top of the J box behind the plug: 
[image: top of box]

And here is the sub-panel showing the three wires in question:

[image: sub-panel]

Comment: btw new cooktop says that if wiring to 4-wire then to leave white wire from power supply capped off as it's unused.

Comment: Is that 50A breaker in your *main* panel (where the main breaker is), or in a *subpanel*? Also, can you post a closeup of where the wires to the range outlet enter the outlet box?

Comment: Furthermore, what make/model is the cooktop, and what diameter is the flex-conduit "whip" on it?  Last but not least, what size is the existing outlet box for the range outlet?

Comment: It’s a Samsung NZ30K7880UG

Comment: About 3” diameter of the flex whip.

Comment: The 50A breakers are in the main panel - I don’t have any sub-panels (unless you count my apartment panel as sub-panel to the building which has some giant panel in the basement serving ... 12-15 apartments).

Comment: Ok the outlet box is I think 4 11/16 kind.  I can’t get a good picture of the conduit entering/attached to the outlet box - I probably could by cutting slightly bigger space on top ...

Comment: Try getting a shot looking up into the top of the outlet box where the wires come in at (no need for drywall butchery here)...and yes, your apartment panel is a subpanel.

Comment: Unfortunately the best picture I can get doesn’t show much - anything in particular you’re looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to see if that's a metal-jacketed (AC/BX) cable or an NM cable coming into your box, as that determines whether grounding to the box is valid or not

Comment: I’ll try to check - if it helps everything else here is BX (but it’s 120 so not sure this confirms it).  If timing helps this plug could not have been wired before mid-80’s.

Comment: If it helps I see no ground wires in the panel but every single regular outlet I tested is properly grounded (in fact I wired one and connected ground wire to jbox and it tests grounded.

Comment: Also, 3" sounds like an illogically large diameter for the flex whip -- I'm thinking it's either 1/2" or 3/4"

Comment: These facts: a) you're in NYC b) in a large commercial complex c) surely well inspected d) metal boxes with what looks like AC (not MC) cable, and e) no ground *wires* in the entire place, yet grounds test good -- combine to be a very strong signal that grounding is present at boxes via AC cables or conduits. My facilities are the same way, no ground *wires* in 4 buildings.

Comment: Sorry was measuring circumference!  Looks like 3/4.

Comment: BTW: I take it you're using a different solution for oven-based cooking?

Comment: I have a combo microwave/convection (countertop) I've had for almost 15 years, I just moved it here and there's space (and power) for it in the back of the kitchen on the counter.  (In the old kitchen it was in its own builtin nook - I had an oven there I literally never used).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In NYC, you will have 208V power.  It's 3-phase, but that won't be an issue.

### Grounding path

Through discussion, we've determined fairly conclusively that a) this complex's wiring *is* grounded, and b) the grounding is via conduit or AC cable jackets, NOT individually run ground wires.  OP reports that his "sub?" Panel has *no ground wires at all*, yet grounds check out on receptacles, so that indicates **boxes are grounded** and ground wires are not run (except inside AC cable). That's not weird; I manage 11 buildings and all of them are that way.  I don't even stock ground wire.

You need to make sure that the wires from the wall are #8 or larger. (The paper padding makes it AC cable, whose internal wires are THHN, allowing the 75C column to be used for 50A).

### If hardwiring

You need to connect the cooktop's green wire to the box*.  The white wire in the box needs to be capped off.

However, there's a snag with hard-wiring. You can't just glorp the wires down "wherever". You need to have the wire-whip enter the box *correctly*, and that means through a knockout.  That knockout needs to be on the face of the box, obviously, so you need a blank junction box cover that has a knockout on its face.

Easy enough, but you don't have a standard box.  Your box presents the receptacle mounting screws for 2 abreast (e.g a 2-gang box) and lacks the corner screws that standard 4x4 box covers use.

So, you'll want to head to the best electrical supply in the city (goes without saying, that *ain't* a big-box store) and find the rare steel blank cover plate *that attaches to the receptacle screws of a 2-gang*.  Ideally this will have a 1/2" or 3/4" trade size knockout on it, but if it doesn't, the shop may cheerfully punch it for you.

1/2" trade size actually uses a 7/8" knockout.
3/4" trade size uses a 1-1/8" knockout.

### Cord-and-plug connection

*Make sure the cooktop allows this before you commit.*

If you want to cord-and-plug connect this, you need to change the receptacle.  That thing is an obsolete, dangerous NEMA 10-50, and must be changed for this application because you need ground and NEMA 10 doesn't have it.

Fit a NEMA 14-50 receptacle.  This has 4 wires.  Fit the white wire to the neutral pin even though this cooktop doesn't use it.

On the cooktop, you'll be replacing the entire whip with a cord, not putting a plug on the end of the whip (which isn't structurally equipped for that).  Buy a 14-50 cord, and attach to the cooktop's terminal block.  Neutral gets wrapped with tape, *not* tied to ground!

---

* The box has a hole in the back tapped #10-32, it's a bit smaller than the other holes.  This takes a #10-32 screw, and they even sell green ground screws just for this.  This needs a #10 solid pigtail, which is tied to your oven's green wire.  DON'T just clump this together with the white wire "just in case", that would create redundant neutral-ground bonds, which can cause all sorts of trouble. Also do not use the pre-made ground pigtails sold at the store, as those will be #14 or #12 and you need #10.  You can buy 1 foot of bare #10 wire cheap.

Comment: I don’t have an oven. Replacing range with induction cooktop *only*.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Edited but that doesn't change any of my answer.

Comment: It sounds like it’s key to find out if box is viable ground and I wouldn’t trust apartment management to know. Is there a way I can test that?

Comment: Also I’m now inclined to hardwire since I wouldn’t be able to utilize the existing plug anyway.

Comment: Liability shift is the reason I want you to ask them. If they tell you wrong, it's on them.  I am 90% confident the box is viable ground since this is AC cable not MC.  If you really wanted to test it, you could throw a 120V load between black and the ground path under test, this would simulate a ground fault of that amperage.  This has a small chance of lighting up kitchen grounds, and a very remote chance of setting the building on fire.

Comment: Since some of the other wiring in this kitchen was done by idiots I’m not sure I want to risk things too much. Having said that I’m going to add a couple of pictures of my subpanel that may help.

Comment: You said I should see if neutral and ground wires in sub panel are on separate buses - I see no ground wires in there at all.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky can you post a photo of where the feeder wires enter that panel?

Comment: Looking at the OP's closeup, I don't think they have a mudring on their box...

Comment: Stick with hard wiring it. I've put six of these in and none of them had a terminal board where you could remove the whip and install a cord and plug. All the wires were crimped to the whip.

Answer (score 4):

### Yeah, that's BX/AC, so ground to the box

Looking at your closeup shot, I can tell that between the fact that the cable armor is stopped by the fitting (instead of a cable jacket, which will poke out into the box through the cable clamp as a general rule), the lack of a ground wire entering the box (which rules out type MC), and the individual paper wraps around the conductors seen protruding into the box (which is characteristic of AC/BX), this circuit, like the rest of your apartment, was wired using type AC (BX) cable, with the armor as the ground path.

### You'll need to hardwire this, using a fitting and a faceplate

Since your cooktop comes with a flex whip and not a cord (or a place for a cord to go), you'll need to hardwire the flex whip to the box.  You'll need a 1/2" flex/MC fitting (the straight vs. 45° vs 90° decision depends on what keeps the whip from trying to bend too tightly, although 90° would be a common choice here) and a 4 11/16" flat faceplate with a 1/2" KO in it for this.  The green wire from the cooktop gets landed on a 10-32 ground screw in the back of the box, the hots from the cooktop connect to the corresponding hot wires in the box with appropriate wirenuts, and another wirenut is used to cap off the neutral wire from the wall by itself, as it's not used in this configuration.  You'll need to attach the fitting and faceplate to the flex whip before you connect the flex whip to the circuit, by the way.

Comment: yep, I had a box of the right size to put on top of existing one and use a straight fitting (out the side) but that made it protrude into the cabinet too much and nearly touch the bottom drawer, so I found a cover with KO and a 90° fitting.  Works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you know which of the 3 wires are your neutral of your existing 50 amp outlet ... In your top picture, of the 3 slots you see, the one on the BOTTOM is where that white wire should be connected to NOW.. That wire will be the one that will connect to the Green one on your flexible metal connection coming out of your induction cooktop. The other two are exchangeable..

Your cooktop is 30 amps, and that 50 amp breaker in your panels needs to be reduced to a 30 amp/ 2,pole. No need to change the wire out, your good there.

At your range plug, if there's room for an extension box which would sit atop your existing wall box, you COULD wire your cooktop to that.

Comment: I'm am unsure that you could put a "plug" on flexible metal conduit... I'd say NO unless there is a plug made for that. In either case, if there is such a plug made, it will have to be 30 amps, and SO WILL your wall outlet.. just like your breaker will be 30 amps... Just like your new induction oven...

Comment: My cooktop isn’t 30A is it?  It says it requires minimum 40A breaker.

Comment: I’m curious where the 30A came from - is it because that plug can be either 30A or 50A?

Comment: My bad, though it said 30. Replace that 50 amp breaker with a 40 then.  There's another way to connect to that existing box after you remove the plug and cover. Your box is either a 4x4 ( 4 square box ) or it's a 4-11/16 box. In either case, take out the old plug and cover, get a "blank" cover and drill a 1/2" conduit hole in it...right in the center of it. Or if you can buy a cover with a 1/2" hole in it. Also buy a 90° flexible conduit connector and attach that to your flexible conduit on your induction oven....

Comment: It’s 4 11/16th box. Is there advantage to wiring a plug - if not I’m inclined to go with hardwiring as instructions recommend.

Comment: @RetiredElectrician -- offsite communication is not the way the Stack works.

Comment: You're "better" in the way of convenience with a plug, but as mentioned before, I haven't never seen one for flexible metal conduit...But one of the the unknowns to me here is "would there be room for it" . Physical  room / spacial challenges always apply when considering new installs. You can indeed buy 4-11/16 blank covers with 1/2" holes in them. And unsure if you clicked the link for the 90° flexible metal conduit connector, but utilizing those two things will be a more compact install anyways *just in case you have any room constraints...* Besides being cheaper on you.... 

Comment: Oh, and one other thing as well..Looking at the length of the wires coming out of your flexible metal conduit from your cooktop.. they "look" a little bit short.  If you're finding that the connecting ( wire nutting ) them becomes difficult due to length, you can remove that tape or insulation, then "unwind" the end of that flexible metal conduit a couple of inches then snip off the excess with tin snips. Make certain you put back that tape or insulation in the same way... Hopefully this helps you...